# Using Dijkstra algorithm in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph, distance, path-finding, adjacency-matrix

I found this function:

```
 function [dist,path] = CSDG_Dijkstra_SP(nodes,segments,start_id,finish_id,L,PlotFlags);
```

which allows me to calculate the the shortest distance and path between points on a map.
The inputs I need are `nodes`, `segments`, `start_id`, and `finish_id`. I already have the following:

```
xyNode=randi([1,100],N,2);
ID=[1:N]'
nodes=[ID,xyNode(:,1),xyNode(:,2)];
```

and `start_id` is the number of the nodes among `N` nodes that I have in my map. 
`finish_id` is for another node (different from this `N` nodes. It is the sink node) which is placed in certain position (center of the map). For this I wrote:

```
for n=1:N
      start_id=n;
      finish_id=(100*sqrt(N)/2),(100*sqrt(N)/2);
      [dist,path]=CSDG_Dijkstra_SPT(nodes,segments,start_id,finish_id)
      output(:,:,n)=[dist,path];
  end
```

As it is defined in this function, the input `segments`  should be an Mx3 matrix with the format `[ID N1 N2]`, where `ID` is an integer, and `N1`, `N2` correspond to entry number in the `nodes` list.

Two nodes, `N1` and node `N2`, are said to be "able to communicate" (i.e. have an *undirected* edge/segment between them) only if the distance between them is less than `100*sqrt(5)`.

How can I get the segments input with this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compute the pairwise distance between your points, then filter it according to the threshold, then the remaining distances are used to construct the "valid" segments.

```
function varargout = q43223243(N, TRSH, MAX_DST)
if nargin == 0
%% DEFINITIONS:
N = 50;
TRSH = 100*sqrt(5);
MAX_DST = 1000;
end
%% The rest...
xyNode = randi(MAX_DST,N,2);
ID = 1:N;
nodes = [ID(:),xyNode(:,1),xyNode(:,2)];
% Find pairwise distance:
D = tril(pdist2(xyNode,xyNode)); % symmetric, so we only take the bottom.
D(D > TRSH | D == 0) = NaN;
% Find positions of valid edges:
[I,J] = ind2sub(size(D), find(~isnan(D)));
% Finally construct the segments array:
segments = [I, J, D(~isnan(D))];
% Outputs
if nargout > 0
  varargout{1} = nodes;
  varargout{2} = segments;
else
  figure();
  line(xyNode(:,1),xyNode(:,2),'LineStyle','none','Marker','o'); hold on;
  gplot(~isnan(D),xyNode,'-r');
end
```

#### Example output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Dev-iL . for `MAX_DST` input, should I compute the distance between the farthest two nodes? And in `xyNode = randi(MAX_DST,N,2);`, have you changed `xyNode` by writing `MAX_DST`, instead of  `xyNode=randi([1,100],N,2);`?

Comment: @snat the function above is just a demonstration. I just made it a bit more general than what you described in the question. 1) Yes (this is just for a scenario with randomly generated points...). 2) Read about `randi`, you don't need to specify the first input as a vector if the minimal value is 1. If you created `xyNode` elsewhere, this won't overwrite _your_ `xyNode` because it's a separate function (with its own scope/workspace).

Comment: In this case I should take `MAX_DST=100`, if I'm right. And another question is that if the positions of nodes are not symmetric, I think I just have to omit `tril`? @Dev-iL .

Comment: @snat It has nothing to do with the positions themselves. When you compute pairwise distance from a vector to itself, you'll always get a symmetric matrix with a zero main diagonal because that's just the way it is.... BTW, if this answer solved your problem, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: I see. Will you kindly answer to one more question? Now the `CSDG_Dijkstra_SPT(nodes,segments,start_id,finish_id,L,PlotFlags)` needs the last two inputs, giving the error `Not enough input arguments.
Error in CSDG_Dijkstra_SPT (line 181)
    if (PlotFlags.SPT==1)`, although in its own example it has not used those inputs and even has not defined them. Any idea? @Dev-iL.

Comment: @snat Looks like your original problem is solved isn't it? As for this new problem, that would be a **[different question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions "at Stack Exchange sites, “chameleon questions” are not quite welcome")**, consider posting it separately.